# Multivariate non-negative, discrete time series forecasting with neural networks

Tags: neural-network, time-series

I have a data set obtained from the event log of a bunch of access points in a building. At the moment I am interested in forecasting, for each access point, the number of connected devices at each access point on a given point in time. The features in this data set are *timestamp*, containing the datetime and *AP1*, ... , *AP9*, containing the (relative) number of connected devices for each access point. An example:

```
> synced_logs[500:515,]
              timestamp 1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
500 2017-09-25 12:55:00 1 0  1 -1 -1  0  1 -1  0
501 2017-09-25 12:56:00 1 0  1 -1 -1  0  1 -1  0
502 2017-09-25 12:57:00 1 0  1 -1 -1  0  1 -1  0
503 2017-09-25 12:58:00 1 0 -1 -1  1  0  1 -1  0
504 2017-09-25 12:59:00 1 0 -1  1  1  0 -1 -1  0
505 2017-09-25 13:00:00 1 0  1  1  1  0 -1 -1  0
506 2017-09-25 13:01:00 1 0  0  1 -1  1 -1 -1  0
507 2017-09-25 13:02:00 1 0  0  1 -1  0 -1 -1  0
508 2017-09-25 13:03:00 1 0 -2  1 -1 -1  3  3  0
509 2017-09-25 13:04:00 1 0  1  0 -1 -1  1 -2  0
510 2017-09-25 13:05:00 1 0  0  0 -1  1 -1  2  0
511 2017-09-25 13:06:00 1 0 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -2  1
512 2017-09-25 13:07:00 1 0 -2 -2 -1  3  1 -2  1
513 2017-09-25 13:08:00 1 0 -2 -2 -1  1 -1 -2 -1
514 2017-09-25 13:09:00 1 0  1 -2 -1  1  0 -2 -1
515 2017-09-25 13:10:00 1 0  1 -2 -1  1 -2 -2 -1
```

(the exact number of already connected devices at the first measurement is not known, so the counts are all relative). The data set spans a period of a week and contains 9803 observations (at the minute level). The data set was transformed from a asynchronous event log to a synchronous time series format. I plan on adding lagged variables to this data set if needed (based on partial auto- and cross-correlation statistics).

I want to try to model the counts using neural networks, but have a few questions:

1. Do neural networks play nice with non-negative, discrete data?
2. Are certain network topologies preferred over others in a case like this? E.g. LSTMs?
3. Is it better to model a multivariate outcome (i.e. a vector a counts) or is it better to fit a model for each access point?